# How to fix issue with MDX - Power PIVOT returning numbers as text

Tags: sql, excel, mdx, powerpivot, datamodel

I am using MDX query designer in PowerPivot to drag the data as well as to create calculated columns.

I want to combine two fields:
one shows one side of accounting account, another opposite side of accounting account.

Measure name is "Amount". The problem is that it returns the values as text and Power Pivot does not allow to convert it in data model.

Below my query:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Amount] AS [Measures].[Obroty WN].Value - [Obroty MA].Value,
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{[Measures].[Amount], [Measures].[Kwota] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Data].[Data finansowa].[Data].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 04].[Kod wymiaru 04].[Kod wymiaru 04].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 04].[Nazwa wymiaru 04].[Nazwa wymiaru 04].ALLMEMBERS * [MPK].[Struktura raportowa MPK].[Poziom 01].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 02].[Nazwa wymiaru 02].[Nazwa wymiaru 02].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 02].[Kod wymiaru 02].[Kod wymiaru 02].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 05].[Kod wymiaru 05].[Kod wymiaru 05].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 05].[Nazwa wymiaru 05].[Nazwa wymiaru 05].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 06].[Kod wymiaru 06].[Kod wymiaru 06].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 06].[Nazwa wymiaru 06].[Nazwa wymiaru 06].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 07].[Kod wymiaru 07].[Kod wymiaru 07].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 07].[Nazwa wymiaru 07].[Nazwa wymiaru 07].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 08].[Kod wymiaru 08].[Kod wymiaru 08].ALLMEMBERS * [Wymiar 08].[Nazwa wymiaru 08].[Nazwa wymiaru 08].ALLMEMBERS * [Konto].[Konta wg numerów].[Syntetyka].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [FK] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Thanks

Comment: Please can you edit your question to use formatting that makes it readable and remove the bold ALL CAPS parts of your question, into normal text as they are very shouty, and are less likely to get you a useful response.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?